# CuI, CuSCN Solubility in Ammonia Solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, solvents

I am trying to dissolve copper(I) iodide and copper(I) thiocyanate in ammonia.  I am quite sure that they both dissolve in liquid ammonia, and are insoluble in ethanol.

If I were to purchase a 2.0M solution of ammonia in ethanol, like the one [here](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?interface=All&term=ammonia&N=0&mode=match%20partialmax&focus=product&lang=en&region=US), would the CuI and CuSCN still dissolve in the ammonia solution?

Also, are there any other solvents that you know of for these materials?

Comment: AFAIK, $\ce{CuI}$ is soluble in pyridine and aqueous potassium/sodium iodides.

Answer (score 2):

The reason these salts are soluble in ammonia (including aqueous ammonia -- so why buy ammonia in EtOH?) is that they form complexes with ammonia:
$$
\ce{CuI}\text{(s)}+2\ce{NH3}\text{(aq)}\to\ce{Cu(NH3)_2^+}\text{(aq)}+\ce{I-}\text{(aq)}.$$
Have fun!